# Javac --add-modules adding multiple modules

Tags: java, java-9, java-module

I have a very simple Java class

```
public class TestAnnotation {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(javax.annotation.Generated.class.getName());
    }
}
```

As expected, this does not compile using JDK 9

```
"c:\Program Files\Java\jdk-9.0.1\bin\javac.exe" TestAnnotation.java
TestAnnotation.java:3: error: package javax.annotation is not visible
                System.out.println(javax.annotation.Generated.class.getName());
                                        ^
  (package javax.annotation is declared in module java.xml.ws.annotation, which is not in the module graph)
1 error
```

Ignoring the error message (and using java.xml.ws instead of the suggested java.xml.ws.annotation), I can get it to compile using

```
"c:\Program Files\Java\jdk-9.0.1\bin\javac.exe" --add-modules java.xml.ws TestAnnotation.java
```

However, looking at [the module graph](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java.se.ee-graph.png) module *java.xml.ws* does not depend on module *java.xml.ws.annotation*, which exports the *javax.annotation* package.

How is it possible this does compile (and run, btw)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`java.xml.ws` does depend on `java.xml.ws.annotation`: http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk/jdk/file/68c6f57c40d4/src/java.xml.ws/share/classes/module-info.java#l46

```
module java.xml.ws {
    requires java.desktop;
    requires java.logging;
    requires java.management;
    requires java.xml.ws.annotation;
    ...
```

I have no idea why this dependency is missing in that picture. Probably they wanted to show only the key links.

Comment: Thanks! Too bad it's not in the [summary](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java.xml.ws-summary.html#modules.summary) either.

Comment: On second thought, they probably only show the transitive dependencies

Comment: @BrechtYperman Yes, you seem to be right. They show only transitive ones.

Comment: Not just the picture, what could be added to the answer a little further is *how is adding one module bringing the other(without transitive dependence) into the module-graph*?